# Recursive Algorithm for the four color theorem

Tags: java, recursion, colors, adjacency-matrix

The problem at hand is to take a map separated into regions as expressed in an adjacency matrix and
using four colors, color the map such that no two contiguous regions share the same color. We will use
an adjacency matrix to encode which region borders on which other region. The columns and rows of
the matrix are the regions while the cells contain a 0 if the two regions are not adjacent and a 1 if they
border. Create a recursive backtracking solution which accepts as interactive input from the user the
number of regions in the map and the filename of the adjacency matrix expressing the maps makeup.

The problem that I am running into is that the first value in countryColor is changed but many of the values in the array are never changed.

```
private static final int[] color = {1,2,3,4};
//this color array is meant to represent 4 colors like red, blue, green, orange etc.

private static int[][] map = {{0,1,1,0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,1,0,1},{1,1,1,1,0,0,0},{1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,1,0,1,0}};
//this is the adjacency matrix showing which countries are next to each other

private static int[] countryColor = new int[7];
//this is the array that holds the color values for each country

private static boolean colorMap(int country ){
    System.out.println("Checking Country "+ country);
    boolean check;
        for(int j= 0;j< countryColor.length; j++){
            if(useColor(country,color[j]) == true)
                countryColor[country] = color[j];
            if(country == countryColor.length-1)
                return true;                       
            check = colorMap(country+1);
            System.out.println(check);
            if(check == true)
                return true;
            countryColor[country]=0;
        }   
    return false;
}

private static boolean useColor(int country, int color){
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length;i++){
        if(map[country][i] == 1&& countryColor[i]==color){
            System.out.println("Nah country " + country +" cant be "+color );
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you share problem statement

Comment: Am I missing something, or did you accidentally reverse your comments for the color array and adjacency matrix?

Comment: I included the problem statement and I fixed the comments

Comment: It looks like you have country 2 next to country 2 in your map which means it cannot get a colour it already has.

Comment: What is `if (country == countryColor.length - 1` supposed to be checking? That's essentially a special condition for country 3?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the adjacency matrix but the countryColor array still reads out as 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

Comment: It is supposed to check for the base case. If the last country was checked and it passed the check for the given color then this would end the recursive loop.

Comment: Its ok Im the one who wrote it and Ive misread it a couple times tonight lol

Comment: Could you change `useColor` to be `for (int i = 0; i < country; i++)`? There's no need to check past the current country because you iterate up from 0.

Comment: well the for loop looks at the adjacency matrix and checks each country that is adjacent to the country in question. so if the country is a adjacent and is the same color then useColor returns as false. The loop checks against every country.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that if `useColor` comes back as false, it doesn't set a color for the current country, but still tries to recursively color the rest of the map.  As an example, we first try and color the first country (country 0) with color 1, which succeeds.  We then try and color country 1 with color 1, which fails because it is adjacent to country 0 which already has that color.  This then tries to recursively color the rest, and if it succeeds then we return true.  What you should be doing is if the current color does not work, then you should continue to the next iteration of the loop trying another color before recursively coloring the rest.

More specifically, you should change

```
if(useColor(country,color[j]) == true)
    countryColor[country] = color[j];
```

to

```
if(useColor(country,color[j]) == true)
    countryColor[country] = color[j];
else
    continue;  //this will try and color the current country with another color
```